# i want to show image instead of showing url

Tags: php, codeigniter

```html
   //

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

this is my html

```
<td width="60" ><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="viewList('<?php echo $record->reimId;?>','<?php echo $this->common_model->getEmployeeById($record->empId);  ?>','<?php echo base_url('uploads/reimbrush') . '/' . $record->reimImage; ?>');" name="viewList" id="viewList" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewListData">View</a></td>
```

how to stop access redirecting URL in Codeigniter

here is my code where url is showing...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  function viewList(reimId,name,docurl)
  {
   //alert("Yes!!!...");
   save_method = 'update';
   $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
   $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
   
   //Ajax Load data from ajax
   $.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo base_url('reimbursement/reimbView/')?>/" + reimId,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
                
    {
                    
     $('#empName').text(name);
                    $('#applidDate').text(data[0].currentDate);
                    $('#reimDate').text(data[0].reimbrushDate);
     $('#reimAmount').text(data[0].totalAmount);
                    $('#reimType').text(data[0].reimbursementtype);
                    $('#member').text(data[0].reimbursementtype);
     $('#reimDescription').text(data[0].reimbursement);
                    $('#billUrl').html('<a href="'+docurl+'" style="color:#062bb3;" target="_blank">'+docurl+'</a>'); 
    },
    
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
     alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }/*,
    complete : function(){
     alert(this.url);
    }*/
   });
  }
 
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function viewList(reimId,name,docurl)
        {
            //alert("Yes!!!...");
            save_method = 'update';
            $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
            $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

            //Ajax Load data from ajax
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('reimbursement/reimbView/')?>/" + reimId,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)

                {

                    $('#empName').text(name);
                    $('#applidDate').text(data[0].currentDate);
                    $('#reimDate').text(data[0].reimbrushDate);
                    $('#reimAmount').text(data[0].totalAmount);
                    $('#reimType').text(data[0].reimbursementtype);
                    $('#member').text(data[0].reimbursementtype);
                    $('#reimDescription').text(data[0].reimbursement);
                    $('#billUrl').html('<a href="'+docurl+'" style="color:#062bb3;" target="_blank">'+docurl+'</a>'); 
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error get data from ajax');
                }/*,
                complete : function(){
                    alert(this.url);
                }*/
            });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: please explain your issue more clearly and only provide information that is necessary. create a MINIMAL verifiable example with a clear problem statement and the debugging statements you have *already* taken

Comment: sir i want to display image but as u see on my viewlist function image url show their how can i show image their.

Comment: well i don't see an image tag anywhere... so that's problem #1

Comment: thnx i figure it out problem